# Question: In Java edition 2.1 Skyblock, when you travel to the Nether, is there lava at the bottom or just void?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Title says all, trying to build a 1:1 replica in Bedrock to play on.

Answer (score 1):

It's just void as in the overworld.